# Find Image Control from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am really new to ASP and C#.
I have a User control which has Two Radio Buttons, and and Image control.
I want to load this control dynamically on click of a button and at the same time give ImageURL to the image control.
FileUpload is on the aspx page.
Can anyone help me??

Control MyUserControl = LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MyUserControl);

I  was able to load the user control.
Now how to provide the imageURL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class MyUserControl:UserControl
{
    public string ImageUrl
    {
        set{ image1.ImageUrl=value;}
        get{return image1.ImageUrl;}
    }
}

var ctrl=LoadControl("MyControl.ascx") as MyUserControl;
if(ctrl!=null)
{
    ctrl.ImageUrl = "image.mpg";
}
```

Comment: I added your code but its giving an error

The type or namespace name 'MyUserControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: problem is at `as MyUserControl`, you need to reference the namespace in which you have defined `MyUserControl`

Answer (score 0):

Expose the image URL in your MyControl.ascx as public
Then casting MyUserControl to your usercontrol and assign the image
example :

```
Control MyUserControl1 = LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
MyUserControl temp = (MyUserControl) MyUserControl1;
temp.ImageURL = "urlhere.jpg";
```

Comment: Hi John Kenedy,
How can i expose the image URL??